# RedBlack and AVL tree c++

Tags: c++, implementation, avl-tree, red-black-tree

I want to understand implementation of red black and AVL trees using C++. I checked some websites about them but most of them are complex and difficult to understand. Could you suggest me some resources please?

Comment: From the site rules: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." I'm sorry, you can try to edit your question and ask something more specific, but requesting for tutorials is considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the basic properties of the two trees. You don't have to limit yourself to one programming language. If you understand these properties,then you can implement it by yourself in any language.

**Properties of Red Black Tree:**

1. A node is either red or black.
2. The root is black. This rule is sometimes omitted. Since the root
   can always be changed from red to black, but not necessarily vice
   versa, this rule has little effect on analysis.
3. All leaves (NIL) are black.
4. If a node is red, then both its children are black.
5. Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes
   contains the same number of black nodes. Some definitions: the number of       black nodes from the root to a node is
   the node's black depth; the uniform number of black nodes in   all
   paths from root to the leaves is called the black-height of the
   red–black  tree.

**Red Black Tree C++ code:**
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-red-black-tree/

**AVL Tree Tutorial:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwzuze_tTwQ

**AVL Tree C++ code:**
https://tfetimes.com/c-avl-tree/